# ActiveStorage variant composite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rails-activestorage

I need to add watermarks to images, cmd ImageMagick command

```
convert image.png watermark.png -composite target.jpg
```

or

```
composite -watermark 30% -tile watermark.png image.png target.jpg
```

How can I do this operation with ActiveStorage::Variant?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def medium_img_watermark
    if self.img_first.attached?
      self.img_first.variant(resize: '1200', quality: 75, density: 96,
                             combine_options: {
                              gravity: 'center',
                              draw: 'image Over 0,0 0,0 "public/logo_white.png"'
                            }).processed
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add simply the gem 'mini_magick', install and follow their instructions.

ActiveStorage will then have access to the API, which you can find here:

```
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php
```

Inside active storage, you can access the API like so:

```
<%= image_tag image.variant(resize: "500x500", monochrome: true) %>
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by adding a constant with the path to the image in the model, and using the draw_over option with variant.

**Model.rb**

```
WATERMARK_PATH = "#{Rails.root}/public/images/watermark.png"
```

**View.erb**

```
<div class="carousel-item ">
      <%= image_tag image.variant(resize: "400x400", combine_options: { gravity: 'center', draw: 'image Over 0,0 0,0 "' + Unit::WATERMARK_PATH.to_s + '"' })%>
</div>
```